# How do I pass parameters to print from the below function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    colors: string[];
}

function printUser(user: User) { 
    console.log(user);
}

printUser({'jonathan ',['red','blue']}); \\ PASSING CORRECT PARAMS
```

How do I pass the param to `printUser` get it printed the whole object in the console log?

Comment: What are you getting in `console.log`?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: I'm not able to execute it because it says with `printUser` - Argument of type '{ 'jonathan ': any; ['red','blue']: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.

Comment: Cool, @Andrew. It works and helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printUser({ name: 'jonathan ', colors: ['red', 'blue']});
```

You have to also pass keys in object, not only values.

Answer (score 1):

Update your function call like

```js
const user1: User = { name: 'jonathan ', colors: ['red', 'blue'] };
printUser(user1);
```

or

```js
printUser({ name: 'jonathan ', colors: ['red', 'blue'] });
```

You have to pass data in the same type i.e `User` as you are expecting in `printUser` function;